# Detect accelerometer in titanium studio

Tags: titanium, accelerometer

I'm new to Titanium mobile development and going to develop an app which will be going to read accelerometer sensed data. Can any body guide me on a proper way? Any resources regarding accelerometer with titanium?

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.0/Titanium.Accelerometer

This is the link to the Titanium API page. They provide an example at the bottom of the page. Can you give more details about what you'd like? I might be able to help more.